# Problem embedding a pylab Figure in a Gtk application using quickly

Tags: application-development, gtk, quickly, matplotlib

I am currently trying to build a simple app that includes some `pylab` figures. I just started to use `quickly` and I am concerned about some import issues. That is, none of the `matplotlib` backends will be able to work.

More specifically, if any of the following `import` statements is uncommented in my main file, then `quickly` will fail to run the app

```
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import FigureCanvasGTK as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkcairo import FigureCanvasGTKCairo as FigureCanvas
```

so there is no way I can embed a plot.

Here is the output of `quickly run` if the `backend_gtk` is uncommented

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed   import gobject._gobject 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size   from gtk import
_gtk 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed   from gtk import _gtk
```

Any idea of what could solve the problem? Do you need more information?

Comment: Question closed during answering... Anyway: you'll need atleast version 1.2.0 of matplotlab, which can be installed by pip if it's not in your repository. Then use the GTK3 backends, for example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html

Comment: Developing GUI apps in Python that run on Ubuntu is widely treated as on-topic on Ask Ubuntu, though I'm not aware of any strong community consensus either way on the issue. This question certainly seems on-topic *since it's about Quickly*, though the answer is not Quickly-specific. This is [answered in a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427726/problem-embedding-a-pylab-figure-in-a-gtk-application-using-quickly-solved#comment554980_427726) and that comment would better be posted as an answer. I've voted to reopen this, though I understand if some people disagree.

Comment: @Timo The question is now reopened. Can you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need atleast version 1.2.0 of matplotlib and then use the GTK3 backends.

Example taken from http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
demonstrate adding a FigureCanvasGTK3Agg widget to a Gtk.ScrolledWindow
using GTK3 accessed via pygobject
"""

from gi.repository import Gtk

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3agg import FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigureCanvas

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit )
win.set_default_size(400,300)
win.set_title("Embedding in GTK")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
a.plot(t,s)

sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
win.add (sw)
# A scrolled window border goes outside the scrollbars and viewport
sw.set_border_width (10)

canvas = FigureCanvas(f)  # a Gtk.DrawingArea
canvas.set_size_request(800,600)
sw.add_with_viewport (canvas)

win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Note: Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have Matplotlib 1.2.0 in the repository, but it is installable through `pip`:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```